# Not going to specific URL this.router.navigate() in AngularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am making a registration form in angularJS and I use the bootstrap template for design.

This is my form and path to the form page is `http://localhost:4200/signup`

```
<form method="post" (submit)='register(username.value,email.value,password.value)'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" #username class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="remail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="remail" #email class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rpassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" #password class="form-control" id="rpassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

But the problem is that it when I click `submit button` or hit `enter`, It automatically refresh the page and shows `Cannot POST /signup`.

As this is my `component.ts file`

```
register(name,email,password) {
this.userService.registerUser(name, email, password).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.success) {
          console.log('reaches');
          this.router.navigate(['user']);
        } else {
          console.log('error');
        }
      });
 }
```

It is trying to go to the `/signup` path in post method but in `component.ts` file I give the path to `'/user'`

How can it automatically go-to `/signup`? And how to stop that.

Comment: what does your user service function this.userService.registerUser() look like? Have you looked at the response and does it have a success property?

Comment: yes I checked , it gives me `success: true `as a result

Answer (score 0):

Your form is trying to post data to a server. It sounds like you don't have a server which can handle the post, so you get the error.

To fix the problem, you need a server which can handle the form post.

Comment: I have the server but here I am not giving the path to the server.

Comment: Then you need to add the path to the server in the form tag with `<form action="<path to server>" method="post">`

Comment: It should be (ngSubmit). Look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Comment: Problem is not (submit) I am able to submit the data in database but don't know why it is not navigating to next page.

Comment: What is the registerUser function doing? Is it returning success?

Comment: Yes, if every thing is fine then it return `success: true`.